# Assignation counting up to maximum

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the below 2 tables:

aux1:

| PC | A | MAXI |
| --- | --- | --- |
| PC1 | A1 | 1 |
| PC1 | A2 | 2 |
| PC2 | A1 | 1 |
| PC2 | A2 | 2 |

aux:

| VK | D | PC |
| --- | --- | --- |
| VK1 | 8 | PC1 |
| VK2 | 7 | PC1 |
| VK3 | 6 | PC2 |
| VK4 | 5 | PC2 |
| VK5 | 4 | PC1 |
| VK6 | 3 | PC1 |
| VK7 | 2 | PC2 |
| VK8 | 1 | PC2 |

I would like to obtain the following output:

| VK | D | PC | A | ORDER_A_PC | ORDER_PC |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| VK1 | 8 | PC1 | A1 | 1 | 1 |
| VK2 | 7 | PC1 | A2 | 1 | 2 |
| VK3 | 6 | PC2 | A1 | 1 | 1 |
| VK4 | 5 | PC2 | A2 | 1 | 2 |
| VK5 | 4 | PC1 | A2 | 2 | 3 |
| VK6 | 3 | PC1 | NA | NA | NA |
| VK7 | 2 | PC2 | A2 | 2 | 3 |
| VK8 | 1 | PC2 | NA | NA | NA |

The logic for the columns is:

A: ordering aux by D desc and partitioning by PC, assign A (A1 or A2) until the count over partition reaches the maxi configured in table aux1 for each PC and A.
ORDER_A_PC: ordered count over partition by A and PC until the count exceeds the maxi for that PC, A in table aux1
ORDER_PC: same as ORDER_A_PC but partitioned by just PC.

```
with aux (vk, pc) as (
    select 'VK1', 'PC1' from dual union all
    select 'VK2', 'PC1' from dual union all
    select 'VK3', 'PC2' from dual union all
    select 'VK4', 'PC2' from dual union all
    select 'VK5', 'PC1' from dual union all
    select 'VK6', 'PC1' from dual union all
    select 'VK7', 'PC2' from dual union all
    select 'VK8', 'PC2' from dual),
aux1 (pc, a, maxi) as (
    select 'PC1', 'A1', 1 from dual union all 
    select 'PC1', 'A2', 2 from dual union all 
    select 'PC2', 'A1', 1 from dual union all 
    select 'PC2', 'A2', 2 from dual)
select * from aux
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nice little problem. You can distribute the assets preprocessing the ranges and then joining by range.

For example, you can do:

```
with aux (vk, pc) as (
    select 'VK1', 'PC1' from dual union all
    select 'VK2', 'PC1' from dual union all
    select 'VK3', 'PC2' from dual union all
    select 'VK4', 'PC2' from dual union all
    select 'VK5', 'PC1' from dual union all
    select 'VK6', 'PC1' from dual union all
    select 'VK7', 'PC2' from dual union all
    select 'VK8', 'PC2' from dual),
aux1 (pc, a, maxi) as (
    select 'PC1', 'A1', 1 from dual union all 
    select 'PC1', 'A2', 2 from dual union all 
    select 'PC2', 'A1', 1 from dual union all 
    select 'PC2', 'A2', 2 from dual),
s as (
  select a.*,
    coalesce(sum(maxi) over(partition by pc order by pc, a 
      rows between unbounded preceding and 1 preceding), 0) + 1 as first_maxi,
    sum(maxi) over(partition by pc order by pc, a) as last_maxi
  from aux1 a
),
x as (
  select a.*,
    row_number() over(order by vk) as rn
  from aux a
),
y as (
  select a.*,
    (select count(*) from x b where b.rn <= a.rn and b.pc = a.pc) as cnt
  from x a
)
select
  y.vk, y.pc, s.a,
  case when s.pc is not null then row_number() 
    over(partition by y.pc, s.a order by y.rn) end as order_a_pc,
  case when s.pc is not null then row_number() 
    over(partition by y.pc order by y.rn) end as order_pc
from y
left join s on s.pc = y.pc and y.cnt between s.first_maxi and s.last_maxi
order by y.rn
```

Result:

```
VK   PC   A       ORDER_A_PC  ORDER_PC
---  ---  ------  ----------  --------
VK1  PC1  A1               1         1
VK2  PC1  A2               1         2
VK3  PC2  A1               1         1
VK4  PC2  A2               1         2
VK5  PC1  A2               2         3
VK6  PC1  <null>      <null>    <null>
VK7  PC2  A2               2         3
VK8  PC2  <null>      <null>    <null>
```

See running example at [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=b9ba4ff93865971547782d541d1ccc12).

Comment: Great solution! Actually I think one of the CTEs (y) is not necessary since that can be achieved with a count over partition by pc order by vk, but the overall solution is valid. I'm now to increase a little bit the riddle. I will post it in a separate question.